# Суммирование поля из другой таблицы

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi-7

Есть две таблицы.

```
Zakaz

ID_Zakaz - ключ
Summ - float значение
```

И вторая таблица

```
Nakladnay
ID_Nakladnay - ключ
ID_Zakaz - ключ заказа
ID_Sum - сумма накладной
```

Как подсчитать общую сумму в таблицу заказ по `ID_Zakaz`
Использую базу данных `SQL Server`

Остановился вот так, не работает

```
 SELECT Zakaz1.ID_Zakaz, Nakladnay.Sum, Zakaz1.sum * Nakladnay.Sum As summa
 FROM Nakladnay, Zalaz1 
 WHERE ID_Zakaz =:ID_Zakaz
```

Comment: Поясните, что хранится в поле `Zakaz.Summ`

Comment: числовое число, оно пустое, я туда хочу хранить сумму

Comment: нужна сумма полей `Nakladnay.ID_Sum` с группировкой по `ID_Zakaz`?

Comment: да, и хранить их в Zakaz.Sum. Использую ADOQuery

Comment: А зачем вам хранить сумму в отдельной таблице? Вы будете их каждые пять минут пересчитывать?

Comment: пересчитывать буду, при изменение данных

Comment: можно и не хранить, это не принципиально

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотреть суммы по заказам:

```
SELECT
   z.ID_Zakaz,
   z.ID_Postavhik,
   SUM(ISNULL(n.Sum,0)) AS summa
FROM Zakaz z
LEFT JOIN Nakladnay n ON n.ID_Zakaz = z.ID_Zakaz
GROUP BY z.ID_Zakaz, z.ID_Postavhik;
```

Обновление данных в таблице `Zakaz`:

```
;with sums AS 
   ( 
    SELECT
      n.ID_Zakaz,
      SUM(n.Sum) AS summa
    FROM Nakladnay n
    GROUP BY n.ID_Zakaz;
   )
UPDATE z 
SET summ = s.summa
FROM Zakaz z 
INNER JOIN sums s
    ON s.ID_Zakaz = z.ID_Zakaz
WHERE z.summ <> s.summa;
```

Дополнительные замечания:

1. Старайтесь всегда использовать `JOIN`, а не объединение таблиц через
   запятую, такой синтаксис в [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server) является нерекомендуемым
   (deprecated). Это означает, что его планируют полностью исключить в
   новых версиях.
2. Не понятно, зачем хранить сумму в таблице `Zakaz`. Она в любом
   случае будет не будет гарантировать актуальности своего значения.
   Если таблица `Nakladnay` имеет большое число значений и
   затруднительно считать суммы при выводе в приложение, то имеет смысл
   фиксировать в таблице заказ итог подсчета на дату или если в
   `Nakladnay` столбец `ID_Nakladnay` автоинкремент то указывать до
   какого его значения сумма посчитана..

Comment: спасибо выводит сумму. А как добавить в первом запросе еще одно поле, чтоб выводило

Comment: Надо в группировку его добавить и в вывод.

Comment: Добавляю вот так
GROUP BY n.ID_Zakaz , n.ID_Postavhik;  ну ругается что не допустимое имя столбца. (Это поле в таблице Zakaz)

Comment: @Ewrei_228 обновил ответ.

Comment: спасибо это работает. Наверно достал вас вопросами, а можно добавить так чтоб и выводила и те записи Zakaz, у которой нету Nakladnay

Comment: @Ewrei_228 вот так. Вообще почитайте про `JOIN` и `GROUP BY`

Comment: @Nakladnay, большое спасибо. Вы меня выручили